# How to capture AWS Lambda's own CRUD events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, slack

Is there any way to capture AWS Lambda's own CRUD events like lambda create, lambda update, lambda delete

I am trying to create an alert system to slack channel on every lambda update

Answer (score 2):

[CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html):

> [Lambda is integrated with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), a service that provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in Lambda. CloudTrail captures API calls for Lambda as events. The calls captured include calls from the Lambda console and code calls to the Lambda API operations.

Additionally, many services (but not Lambda) send [change events directly to EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html).  EventBridge is notified when an RDS Instance is deleted, for instance.  For finer-grained monitoring, consider the [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) service.